# input and output speed between functions

Tags: c

I am a newbie in c. I am wandering that the input and output speed between these I/O functions. They take almost the same amount of time when input is just some strings, but I think it will makes a different when the input is very large. So I want to know which way I can use to read input the most efficiently.

for input: `scanf()`, `fgets`(), `getchar`(), `gets`()...
for output: `printf()`, `puts()`, `putchar()`...

for case "205 36 12"

```
int a, b, c;
scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

is the above faster than below or otherwise?

```
int a, b, c;
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, 100, stdin);
sscanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

and for output "abcde"

```
char buf[10] = "abcde";
puts(buf);
```

is the above faster than below or otherwise?

```
char buf[10] = "abcde";
printf("%s", buf);
```

Comment: The difference between `scanf()` and `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` is likely to be negligible. But note that they're not actually equivalent, due to the way the newline is processed (fgets consumes it, scanf doesn't). It generally doesn't make sense to make performance comparisons between code that works differently.

Comment: Isn't the limitation how fast the input can be typed (or redirected from file)? Practically there will be no useful speed gain in your options.

Comment: "is the above faster than below or otherwise?" - In all of these cases, the bottleneck is the user. Each of the methods listed will block until the user finishes providing input. It doesn't make much sense to try optimizing this use case.

Comment: `puts` and `printf("%s", ...)` are not equivalent. `puts` outputs a newline.

Comment: For output, `puts` is going to be mariginally faster because it doesn't need to interpret the format string; `printf` does. Also, the two methods may flush output at different intervals. But again, this is hardly considered an optimization at the C level. The compiler will generate the most optimal assembly in your case and the performance difference is negligible in nearly all cases. Chances are the compiler converts your `printf` example into a `puts` since the output isn't dynamic.

Comment: Actual i/o speed ends up being remarkably complicated, depending on all sorts of factors, many of which are not under your control.  I don't believe it's possible to make any generic pronouncements about any of the i/o functions you've asked about.  Everything — everything! — depends on your exact program, and how much data it's reading/writing, and where it's reading/writing it to/from, and whether you're handling UTF-8, and which OS it's running under, and how much spare memory there is for the OS to use for a disk cache, and what kind of disk or ethernet controller you have, and...

Comment: I don't want to throw cold water on your curiosity, because curiosity is a wonderful thing, but I'm the opposite of a C newbie, and I can rarely predict with any accuracy whether a given i/o scheme is going to be surprisingly more, or surprisingly less, efficient than I would have expected.  All I know is that I — still! — get surprised *all the time*.  So if you're just starting out, my advice to you is to learn *functionally* how those various techniques work, which ones are more or less functional or convenient, without worrying too much yet about which are more or less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am a newbie in c.

Then chances are you don't need to worry about these types of micro-optimizations, as the compiler will optimize your code for you.

Let's go over the input routines you are interested in.

**scanf()** - This is for parsing data using a format string. This method also blocks until a data source finishes entering data.

**fgets()** - A good general method for reading from a file stream. It also provides a max size argument to help mitigate buffer overflows. `fgets` does not parse data from a format string, so it is slightly more optimal in cases where you don't need to parse data.

**getchar()** - This gets a single character at a time. With large data, it would involve a large amount of calls and is therefore not efficient.

**gets()** - This is an extremely dangerous function to use because it does not bound the input. It's very easy to cause a buffer overflow in `gets()`. You should never use `gets()`.

Regarding output, if you look at the assembly produced by `x86-64 gcc 13.1` you'll see that your output functions produce nearly the same assembly up until the system call, which is related to the compiler optimizing your code.

```
char buf[10] = "abcde";
printf("%s", buf);
```

produces

```
        movabs  rax, 435475931745
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-10], rax
        mov     WORD PTR [rbp-2], 0
        lea     rax, [rbp-10]
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
```

and

```
char buf[10] = "abcde";
puts(buf);
```

produces

```
        movabs  rax, 435475931745
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-10], rax
        mov     WORD PTR [rbp-2], 0
        lea     rax, [rbp-10]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    puts
```

The `printf` function uses a format string to create the output data while `puts` uses the data without formatting. Due to this, `puts()` will perform slightly better with respect to time, but again the result is marginal. True optimizations are related to time and space complexity.

A rule of thumb - You can use `puts()` if you don't need to format your data. You can use `printf()` if you do. Both will have similar runtime performance and technically the data isn't flushed to the output device until later.

Note: `puts()` places a newline at the end of the data while `printf` does not.

Comment: `puts` outputs a newline while `printf` doesn't, so it doesn't make sense to compare their speed. If you change the `printf` to be `printf("%s\n", ...)`, the compiler will probably optimize it into a `puts`, so there's no need for your rule of thumb.

Comment: @interjay yes in the example `printf("%s\n", ...)` the compiler will likely optimize into a `puts(...)` call, but that is not the case for other usage such as `printf("%s %x\n", ...)`, so I would say there is a still a meaningful distinction between the usage of one versus the other. My "rule of thumb" is trying to say "if you don't need to format the data, just use `puts()`."

Answer (score 0):

Most of young programmers give a lot of importance to speed of programs. Speed may be an objective, but the goal is to give the best solution to a problem.

What's about Stability, Portability, Maintainability ?

Think about design not speed. If your program is correctly designed it may be easy to replace / test the way you perform a task.

So You want fast function to read / write file:

These functions are already quite fast to read data from user input or files. But, if the program has to read / write huge amount of data you may use some more advanced methods like memory-mapped-files on windows or mmap on Linux / MacOS/iOS/Android.

I made some benchmarks a few years ago on Linux (Debian 8 on with intel Core I7 and 16Gb ram) to determine the fastest way to read a file of about 3GB from a Seagate mechanical HD.

a) char by char with fgetc() it took 7 sec 37249 msec.

b) through a buffer with fread() it took 0 sec 240579 msec.

c) through page files with mmap() it took 0 sec 101967 msec.

with msec: microseconds.

Since SSD disks exists, read/write is nearly the same even if you choose the worst functions to perform it.
For faster read/write you may also take Hardware architecture in consideration. For example, some RAID configuration can improve read/write speed.

Think also about other programs that run in parallel. If your program take too many resource, It may run fast, but the other task may be impacted by a lack of system resources...

### Example

Here is an mmap() example in C. It can be ported in C++.

```
/*
     readmmap.c
     Get the file to read size with stat() that return the struct:

     struct stat {
    dev_t     st_dev;      
    ino_t     st_ino;      
    mode_t    st_mode;     
    nlink_t   st_nlink;    
    uid_t     st_uid;      
    gid_t     st_gid;      
    dev_t     st_rdev;     
    off_t     st_size;     
    blksize_t st_blksize;  
    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;   
    time_t    st_atime;    
    time_t    st_mtime;    
    time_t    st_ctime;    
};

     Then read file content with mmap() !
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void checkargs(int argc, char **argv);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     struct stat statbuffer;
     int res;
     char *filename;
     int fd;
     void *mmapdata;

     checkargs(argc, argv);

     puts("get file size with stat().");

     filename = argv[1];
     res = stat(filename, &statbuffer);

     if(res==0)
     {
             puts("stat() success !");
             printf("File size %s is %ld bytes.\n", filename, statbuffer.st_size);
     }
     else
     {
             puts("Error: function stat() failed.");
             exit(2);
     }

     /* void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset); */
     fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
     mmapdata = mmap( NULL
                                , statbuffer.st_size
                                , PROT_READ
                                , MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_POPULATE
                                , fd
                                , 0
                                );
     if(mmapdata != MAP_FAILED)
     {
             puts("mmap() success !");

             munmap(mmapdata, statbuffer.st_size);
     }
     else
     {
             puts("Error: mmap() returned MAP_FAILED !");
             exit(3);
     }

     return 0;
}

/* checks that the command is called with an argument */
void checkargs(int argc, char **argv)
{
     if(argc==2)
     {
             puts("ok, program called with an argument");
             printf("equals to '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
     }
     else
     {
             puts("usage:");
             printf("\t%s <file_to_read>\n", argv[0]);
             exit(1);
     }
}
```

For examples of Windows Memmory-Mapped files in C/C++ this page gives exhaustive information: [Managing Memory-Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms810613(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).